# Keyboard shortcut to lock screen stops working

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

I've set the keyboard shortcut <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to lock my screen. Several times I've tried to lock the screen and it just pulls up the super menu.

When I go back and check the keyboard shortcut it is still set and listed as <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. Resetting the shortcut to <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> restores functionality for a time. I can't tell what's triggering this failure.

Any input would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this issue resolved itself. It may have been related to updates, but I don't lose the binding on the shortcut anymore when I restart.

Answer (score 1):

Check your shortcuts and custom ones to see if there is something stealing it?
The default lock screen is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> so maybe something already exists or another program is stealing it.

Comment: I didn't find anything else assigned to super+L when looking through the list of keyboard shortcuts. In the past when I've tried to override an existing shortcut I've gotten an error about it.

I'll try Ctrl+Alt+L next time super+L stops working to see if it's reverting to default.

Comment: Restarting breaks the shortcut as well.